# How can I convert .mhx (motorola s record) file format in .hex (intel hex) file format?

Tags: python, string, file, type-conversion, hex

I tried to use the `bincopy` library but it doesn't convert well or it gives an error. I also tried to split each line in the file but I don't know how to transform those strings.

```
 import bincopy
 f = bincopy.BinFile("test.mhx")
 print(f.as_ihex())
```

Here's the error message:

[image: Screenshot]